# Wrong table cell icon content tint on Big Sur

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, macos-big-sur

I am currently migrating my app to Big Sur, however I can't get `NSTableCellView`s to properly behave. Big Sur now uses the system tint for template images in the table cells image view, like you see for example in Finder here:

[image]

Now for the most part this works fine in my `NSTableView`s (of type source list), however some cells do not seem to apply the tint until I select the table cell. I tried everything, including just using a fresh `NSOutlineView` and `NSTableCellView`s without any modification, with no success.

Here is how it looks for me:

[image]

The first cells of the table always appear untinted when displayed first. Does anyone know what could cause this?

PS: I suspect an issue with `NSImageView`, because when I manually set the tint color on the image view, the tint also only starts appearing after I select the cell at least once:

```
cell.imageView?.contentTintColor = .red
```

As far as I can tell this is an Apple SDK bug.

Implementing the following and just returning the accent color seems to mitigate this issue, yet not resolve it completely. It can still happen that single icons are untinted.

```
extension MyController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {

    @available(OSX 11.0, *)
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
                     tintConfigurationForItem item: Any) -> NSTintConfiguration? {
        .init(preferredColor: .controlAccentColor)
    }
}
```

However I don't think this should be required.

PS: Even with this "fix" cell icons have no tint applied sometimes.

Comment: I have no fix, unfortunately, but I can confirm you're not the only one seeing this behavior. Have you filed a Radar?

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Fix

If you're using Interface Builder:

1. Select the `NSTableCellView` with the icon in it.
2. REMOVE the connection between the `imageView` and the `cellView`.
3. Select the `imageView` in the cell and set a tint color manually, using the property inspector. (You can select "accent color", which will still provide the dynamic accent color tint.)

Now the NSOutlineView will no longer magically change the tint color at random times, since it can't find the NSImageViews in the cells.

#### Drawbacks:

1. You can't use the `tintConfigurationForItem` API any longer.
2. The OutlineView will no longer automatically reduce the opacity of the icons when the window loses key status. (You can do this manually by walking the rows, finding `NSImageView`'s, and setting the value yourself. Whether that's performant for your use-case is a question.)

#### Conclusion:

I do think you're right: someone at Apple screwed up tinting somewhere. Apple engineering will get around to fixing that sometime between 2035 and the heat death of the universe.

For me, icons go to 100% black when I reload the outlineView and then change back to their correct tint when I select and then de-select a row. After this is done once, the issue does not reoccur until the app is relaunched.

Comment: Looking forward to reading the fixed patch notes while orbiting a red dwarf.